# Edit config and database settings of Codeigniter via frontend

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a install script like Magento for a Website, which can be re-used for future projects in CodeIgniter. The purpose of the install script is to create some tables and some basic data for the website such as site name, description, OG tags etc.

There is a prerequisite file say, `install-prerequisite.php` by which the user will enter the database host, database username, database password and submit the credentials. The prerequisite is excluded from the CodeIgniter's index.php using .htaccess so as to exclude the database connection.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|install-prerequisite\.php|robots\.txt)
```

The values from the install-prerequisite.php has to be updated in `database.php` of the CodeIgniter. This has also to be validated for successful connection too. Is this possible?

Similarly can the `config.php` be edited by the data from the forms? User can edit the value for `sess_cookie_name`, `sess_expiration` etc. from a web page and update to the `config.php`.

**Synoptic:**

1. Update database.php parameters programmatically.
2. Update config.php parameters programmatically.
3. Check connection with parameters saved in database.php, from install.php.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store the custom values like database name, user, pass in a Global Database where is accessible by login and not in the file "install-prerequisite.php".

Then you can load the user's database and config by entering his data and connect manually:

https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html
https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html

by putting this function in the construct of every page or in a pre-controller hook.

This enables you to edit the configurations without editing phisically the .php file in the config folder (which i think it's bad) and overrides the general config values.

For example:

```
$confvalues = $this->db->where('name','dude')->get('user_configs')->row();

$db['dude']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['dude']['username'] = $confvalues->db_user;
$db['dude']['password'] = $confvalues->db_pass;
$active_group = "dude";
```

Now when you go $this->db it will use the dude's Database

```
$this->config->set_item('sess_cookie_name', $confvalues->sess_cookie);
```